# Path integrals and classical paths obtained via saddle point integration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, path-integral, semiclassical

EDIT: Focussed my question more based on @octonion's comments

Say one is interested in the following action, 
$$S[\{\phi_i(x,t), \tilde{\phi_i(x,t)}\}] = \int \mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}^d x\left(\tilde{\phi_i}\dot{\phi_i} - H(\phi_i, \tilde{\phi_i}) \right) .$$

And the integral, $$\int\mathrm{D}[\phi,\tilde{\phi}]\exp(-S) \propto \exp(-S_{cl})$$
this would be dominated by contribution's from the "classical path" which can be be computed using Laplace's method/saddle point integration. In particular in the case where we only have $\phi,\tilde{\phi}$, and $H$ is an integral of motion, one cane solve for $\tilde{\phi} (\phi)$ and compute $S_{cl}$ as follows (would this be correct?) In general one would have to solve a shooting problem and solve the hamiltonian equations of motion ( I am assuming)?

Expanding $S = S_{cl} + \delta S +\frac{1}{2} \delta^2 S + \dots$

I understand the first variation, $\delta S$ is supposed to yield the equations of motion, which would read something like,

$$\dot{\phi_i} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial \tilde{\phi_i}}$$
$$\dot{\tilde{\phi_i}} = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial {\phi_i}}$$

Which means the first variation should read something like, $$\delta S = \int{\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d^d}x[ \delta \tilde{\phi} (\dot{\phi} - \partial_\tilde{\phi} H)} + \delta \phi (-{\dot{\tilde{\phi}} - \partial_\phi H)}]. $$
I can get the first term, by perform $$\frac{\delta S}{\delta \tilde{\phi_i}}\delta \tilde{\phi} = \int dt d^dx (\dot{\phi}-\partial_\tilde{\phi}H)\delta \tilde{\phi}. $$

To get the second term, one does an integration by parts over time to move the time derivative, $\int d^dx\int \mathrm{d}t\tilde{\phi_i}\dot{\phi_i} = \text{surface} - \int d^dx \mathrm{d}t \phi_i \dot{\tilde{\phi_i}}$. Taking the functional derivative, the surface term is killed, and we get the second equation of motion. I guess this was one of my original questions, and is resolved (unless I made a computation/logic mistake in this step).

In particular in the case where we only have $\phi,\tilde{\phi}$, and $H$ is an integral of motion, one cane solve for $\tilde{\phi} (\phi)$ by setting $H = 0$and compute $S_{cl}$ as follows (correct me if I am wrong) In general one would have to solve a shooting problem and solve the hamiltonian equations of motion (correct me if I am wrong).

$$S_{cl} = \int\tilde{\phi}(\phi) \mathrm{d}\phi.$$

Following Laplace's Method, $$\int e^{Mf(x)} d\vec{x} = (\frac{2 \pi}{M})^{d/2} \frac{e^{Mf(x^*)}}{\det{(-Hf(x^*)})^{1/2}} $$ where $\vec{x}$ is a $d$-dimensional vector, and $H$ is the hessian matrix, and $x^*$ is the stationary point.

Using the taylor expansion in the original functional integral, and integrating over the deviations from the classical path one expects to get something like,

$$ \int \mathrm{D[\delta \phi]} \mathrm{D[\delta \tilde{\phi}]} \exp(-(S_{cl} + \delta S + \delta^2 S)) =  e^{-S_{cl}}\int \mathrm{D[\delta \phi]} \mathrm{D[\delta \tilde{\phi}]} \exp(-\frac{1}{2} (\vec{\delta}\cdot H \cdot \vec{\delta}^T) $$

where, 
$$ \vec{\delta}\cdot H \cdot \vec{\delta}^T= \begin{pmatrix} \delta \phi & \delta \tilde{\phi} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\delta^2_{\phi, \phi}S & \delta^2_{\phi, \tilde{\phi}}S\\\ \delta^2_{\tilde{\phi}, \phi}S & \delta^2_{\tilde{\phi}, \tilde{\phi}}S\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \delta \phi \\ \delta \tilde{\phi} \end{pmatrix}$$

Gaussian integration of the $\delta^2S$ term yields the prefactor term.

Now, my main questions. Have the following terms been evaluate correctly? 
$$\delta^2_{\phi, \phi}S = - \partial_{\phi,\phi} H$$
$$\delta^2_{\tilde{\phi}, \tilde{\phi}}S = - \partial_{\tilde{\phi},\tilde{\phi}} H$$

$$\delta^2_{\phi, \tilde{\phi}}S = - \partial_{\phi,\tilde{\phi}} H$$
$$\delta^2_{\tilde{\phi}, \phi}S = - \partial_{\tilde{\phi},\phi} H$$

I am guessing the $\dot{\phi}, \dot{\tilde{\phi}}$ terms vanish, upon taking the second derivative?

How will then a determinant be extended to functional derivatives, and how would the hessian be evaluated along the classical path?

Comment: Your first question on how the first order variation vanishes is answered by simple integration by parts to bring the time derivative over to the $\bar{\phi}$ factor. Your second question is more involved, but if you look how say the harmonic oscillator is treated in any textbook on path integrals you'll see how the determinant is calculated. By the way, it is considered bad form to package two completely unrelated questions together here (it's considered bad form to answer in the comments too, but whatever).

Comment: @octonion Thanks for your comment about the integration by parts. Can't believe i missed that. I tried focussing my question to the hessian and its evaluation. Is it more in line with the community guidelines now?

Comment: Yes it is better now I think. Your second, main, question is still a difficult and technical one. Maybe some kind person will attempt an answer, but I think you'll have better luck if you see how it is done in a textbook first (Chapter 1 of Nahahara's Geometry, Topology and Physics has it), and then ask a specific question if you have one. Good luck!